# How long to crack an 8 character WPA2 hash if first char is known

Tags: password-cracking, wpa2, hashcat

I know the first char is A and it's all upper alphanumeric. Is there a way to estimate how long a mid level single GPU using hashcat would take to crack it?

Comment: It would take the same amount of time as it takes to brute-force guess a 7 character uppercase alphanumeric password.  It depends entirely on how many guesses your computer can make per second.  Assuming 34 characters [A-Z0-9], it would take 7^34 operations at most, and (7^34)/2 operations on average.  ("mid level single GPU" is not something that we can convert to operations/sec).

Comment: Or is that 34^7...  I never can remember, never needed to know for myself, and will only bother to remember when (if) I ever actually do need to know... ;-)

Comment: @Ghedipunk it's 34^7. The way I remember it is with the extreme case. If I have only 1 possible letter there's only 1 possible guess (e.g. 1^7=1). The wrong alternative would be 7^1=7 which is intuitively wrong.

Comment: I think I can remember the second char also its either 2  or 3 different chars, D, T or Z I think, can I configure hashcat with these chars so it just searches for the following 6 chars?

Comment: A-Z0-9 is 36 characters, not 34.

Comment: Thanks, @noslenkwah, and taking it to an even more extreme: 0 characters. 0^7 = 0; 7^0 = 1... There should be no possible guesses with 0 characters, so your way of taking it to extremes makes sense.  Steve: I don't consider K or S to be distinct letters from C, since C can fill both those roles.  (Poe's Law warning; I'm trying to humorously admit that I just didn't even attempt to spare any extra brain cells for a throwaway comment on a question that will probably be closed; Steve is right of course.)

Comment: And, OP:  I'm fairly sure the manual for hashcat can show you how to configure hashcat.  At least, I sincerely hope it does.

Comment: Digits are 0-9. I guess you mean "characters" then?

Answer (score 2):

If the passphrase is exactly 8 characters long and the first character is known, then only 7 need to be brute forced. Assuming characters are 0‒9 and A‒Z, the maximum number of combinations is 36<sup>7</sup>.

An AMD Radeon RX480 GPU can go through approximately 170,000 candidate WPA2 passwords per second. This means it will take around 36<sup>7</sup> / 170000 seconds *at most* to exhaust all possible 7 character upper alphanumeric passwords, and half that on average. This equates to an average of 2.5 days.

Note that higher-end GPUs and clusters of GPUs can crack such a password, and stronger ones, much more quickly. [From Twitter](https://twitter.com/tinkersec/status/1096046635593928704), 8x 2080Ti GPUs can crack any 8 character password in ~2.5 hours!

Comment: [This](https://twitter.com/tinkersec/status/1096046635593928704) may be relevant.

Comment: @MechMK1 True, but 8 high-end GPUs probably don't qualify as "a mid-level single GPU"

Comment: True, hence why it's more of a "further reading" kind of thing. But a 2080 can be gotten for around 700€, making the total cost of such a cracking rig around 6000€, which is totally affordable for an attacker. Even with just 4x2080's, it's take around 2 hours to crack.