# Is it beneficial to know the first char of a wpa2 hash

Tags: password-cracking, wpa2, hashcat

All I will need to check is AAAAAAAA - AZZZZZZZ.

So I will only have to check the A's but will checking the A's be faster knowing the first char , I can't see why it would be as it would have to check every combination anyway?

Comment: You literally asked the same question here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/214502/how-long-to-crack-an-8-digit-wpa2-hash-if-first-char-is-known

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check AAAAAAAA-AZZZZZZZ, but that's still 26 times faster than checking AAAAAAAA-ZZZZZZZZ.

That speed increase is significant, so knowing the first character (or any other character) is really worth it.